# Sum of all matches in table in excel

Tags: excel, sum

I have a query on how to find out the sum of all the matches in the given table.
Let's say there are 5 columns.
Text 1 in the column11 which I need to match. If column1 matches then I need to find the value of column4 and add them all together.
I tried VLOOKUP, but it gives only one value at a time for one particular value. FILTER gives me the complete table for column1 matches.

Please suggest how can I do it.

Comment: Sumif or sumifs?

Comment: A picture says a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain you would have success if you were to use =Sumif statements. Are you able to provide an image of your workbook so i can see the data in question.

Comment: please use a comment for this, it doesn't seem to be a completed answered